# Looking for table of special values of the Dirichlet $L$-function

Tags: dirichlet-series, l-functions, dirichlet-character

For double checking calculations I made I'd like to find a table of values of $L(-1,\chi_D)$ for small positive fundamental discriminats $D$. It there a table somewhere in the internet? Where?

With $\chi_D$ I mean the Dirichlet character associated to the fundamental discriminant $D$ and with $L(\cdot, \chi_D)$ the respective L-function. I know that you can compute those values using [those formulars](https://mathoverflow.net/a/84817) but for checking my own computations I'd like to have a reference whicdh simply states the result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, it is trivial to compute $L(-1,\chi_D)$, it reduces to the second derivative of $$-\frac12\sum_{m=1}^D \chi_D(m)\frac{x e^{-x m}}{e^{Dx}-1}$$ at $0$.

Comment: Is there no table for those values for all positive $D<10000$?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Computing $\chi_D$ ?

Comment: I'm not stuck. I'm asking for a reference table.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask a table for something trivial to compute. "checking my own computations" means that you don't understand why it is trivial.